# zlib.h not found on SUSE under any include folder but libz.so.1 exist

Tags: linux, git, makefile, suse

I am trying to build git on SLES 11.3 VM using make, but make fails with error "cache.h:39:18: warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory".

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.mak.autogen
config.status: executing config.mak.autogen commands
linuxcli: bimaljha/git/git-master> make
    * new build flags
    CC credential-store.o
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:39:18: warning: zlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:41: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'z_stream'
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
linuxcli: bimaljha/git/git-master>
```

I tried to install the zlib as root, but it is already at latest level.

```
linuxcli: /root> zypper install zlib
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'zlib' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'zlib-1.2.7-0.10.128.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.
linuxcli: /root>
```

I checked `zlib.h` under `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` but there is no `zlib.h` file:

```
linuxcli: /usr/include> ls zlib*
ls: cannot access zlib*: No such file or directory
linuxcli: /usr/include> cd ../local/include
linuxcli: usr/local/include> ls zlib*
ls: cannot access zlib*: No such file or directory
linuxcli: usr/local/include>
```

How to get or where to find it? Only `zypper` command works on my system. Thanks.

Comment: So sorry that my last reply was that poor... Please, follow the tips provided by the following link to build up a version of Python compiled with shared libraries from various modules (zlib an OpenSSL in the example, but tested as well with SQLite). http://theo.cc/blog/2016/02/29/Compile-Python-2-7-OpenSSL-and-zlib-with-a-Custom-Prefix/ You can install at /usr/local or whatever if you may not override existing Python binaries (coming, for instance, from the distro RPM). My apologies. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

I think zlib-devel should be installed.

Comment: It is not working. See the result:
linuxcli: usr/local/include> zypper install zlib-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package 'zlib-devel' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
linuxcli: usr/local/include>

Comment: Search that package first: zypper se zlib-devel

Comment: `linuxcli: /root> zypper se zlib-devel 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No packages found.
linuxcli: /root> zypper install zlib-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Package 'zlib-devel' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
linuxcli: /root> 
`

Answer (score 0):

You can find zlib.h in zlib source package. I try though to install once the header file was installed, but no success...